Вытягивание и разбиение текста на числа и фразы
Расписание университета идёт по ссылкам, то есть сначала идёт ссылка на коды факультетов, затем они используются для определения курса и номера групп и т.д. И коды факультетов имеют такой вид:
{"1354":"Биотехнологи","1018":"Инженеры","3477":"Программисты"};
И есть код, который вручную мы меняем, чтобы вытягивать расписание каждого факультета по отдельности, так как никакой зависимости между кодами нету (вместо ХХХХ - код факультета):
for course in range(1, 7):
                groups = await get_groups(ХХХХ, course)
                for group in groups:
                    for week_number in range(1, 49):
                        schedule = await get_schedule(group['ID'], week_number)
                        if len(schedule) != 0:
                            for dictionary in schedule:
                                async with conn.transaction():
                                    await insert_schedule(conn, dictionary, i)
                                    i += 1

Подскажите пожалуйста, как автоматизировать этот процесс, потому что расписание периодически меняется, и очень долго его обновлять для 25 факультетов по очереди

Понятно, что ничего не понятно. Составьте вопрос получше пожалуйста.
Желательно укажите входные данные (все), что именно и как надо получить.
